# How do I change activation function of LinearLayer[] in NetGraph

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to analize a network such that all neurons of its hidden layers output `LogisticSigmoid[w.x+b]`, which is one of the most common ouputs analized in a neuron. Is there a way to combine `LinearLayer[]` that gives output w.x+b and the `LogisticSigmoid` function? I looked for an option of changing the activation function in `LinearLayer[]` but I did not find it.

Note: I do not want to use twice ammount of hidden layers by first applying `LinearLayer[]` and then `ElementWiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]`, I would like the network to be more compact.
How would I do that?

Comment: But `ElementWiseLayer` doesn't contain any parameters, it's the same as changing activation function for `LinearLayer`. You don't even have to apply `ElementWiseLayer`, just `LogisticSigmoid` works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess maybe you know the function in `Keras`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(10,)))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Note, that is Dense layer rather than linear layer, so it have the option that can define the activation function.

In MMA, that is simple.

```
Dense[outDims_, "activation" -> act_] := 
 Sequence[LinearLayer[outDims], 
  Switch[act, "tanh", ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], "relu", 
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], "sigmoid", 
   ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]]]

NetChain[{Dense[5, "activation" -> "sigmoid"], 
          Dense[5, "activation" -> "sigmoid"], 
          Dense[5, "activation" -> "sigmoid"]}, "Input" -> 10]
```

[image]